# save_system on non writable file MATLAB command

Tags: matlab

I try to save mdl in old fomart

```
save_system(fullfile(fullpath, myModel(k).name), fullfile(fullpath, myModel(k).name),'SaveAsVersion', 'R2011b');
```

I'm getting an error saying that the file I'm trying to save is not writable
how could I make it writable ?
I don't find a similar arg as for copyfile(...'f')

any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to modify file attributes:

```
fname=fullfile(fullpath, myModel(k).name);
fileattrib(fname,'+w');
```

You could also use java:

```
fname=fullfile(fullpath, myModel(k).name);
java.io.File(fname).setWritable(true)
```

Comment: also applicale to a folder recursively ?

Comment: Check the documentation for `fileattrib`, you have to set the fourth input parameter to `s`.